# SharePoint Online: Skip Property doesn't work with Order By in paging using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, client-object-model, csom, paging

I am trying to fetch the contents of Document Library using paging. For this, I am skipping the resources using `ListItemCollectionPosition` and getting maximum resources using `<RowLimit>` in `CamlQuery`. While everything works fine when `OrderBy` is not included, `Skip` doesn't work when I add `OrderBy` in `CamlQuery`. I am using below code to achieve the same:

```
var newObjClientContext = this.GetSharePointClientContext(accessToken, fullUri);
WebCollection collWeb = newObjClientContext.Web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser(new SubwebQuery());
var documentLibrary = newObjClientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(docID);

ListItemCollectionPosition itemPosition = new ListItemCollectionPosition();
                        itemPosition.PagingInfo = string.Format("Paged=TRUE&p_ID={0}", iSkip);   //Skip thingy doesn't work with Order By

ListItemCollection ltitems = null;

string vquery = @"<View >
                <Query>
                    <Where> 
                        <Or> 
                            <Eq>
                                <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /> 
                                <Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value>
                            </Eq> 
                            <Eq>
                                <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /> 
                                <Value Type='Lookup'>0</Value>
                            </Eq> 
                            </Or> 
                        </Where>
                        <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' Ascending='TRUE'></FieldRef></OrderBy>                                        
                    </Query>
                    <RowLimit>" + recCount + @"</RowLimit>
                    </View>";

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = itemPosition;  //This is ignored.
camlQuery.ViewXml = vquery;
ltitems = documentLibrary.GetItems(camlQuery);
newObjClientContext.Load(documentLibrary);
newObjClientContext.Load(ltitems, lists => lists.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(l => l.ParentList));

newObjClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

How can I implement paging using above code?